# Как вывести максимальные значения двух столбцов для каждого значения ключа (ключ в еще одном столбце? postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter

У меня есть таблица tab из 3х столбцов (ниже пример заполнения):

```
key col1 col2
1 10 200
1 20 100
1 20 0
2 30 500
2 30 400
2 30 300
```

Мне нужно вывести в каждом столбце (col1, col2) максимальные значения для каждого значения ключа.

То есть ожидаемый ответ на примере такой:

```
key col1 col2
1 20 200
2 30 500
```

Я пробовал так. С использованием оконной функции в select:

```
create tab_ext as select
*, 
max(col1) over (partition by key) as col1_max, 
max(col2) over (partition by key) as col2_max
from tab;
```

Затем использовать distinct

```
select

distinct key, col1_max as col1, col2_max as col2
from tab_ext
```

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, более лаконичный способ достичь результат

Comment: `select key, max(col1), max(col2) from tab group by key`. P.S. Мне интересно как вы дошли в изучении SQL до оконных функций, пропустив при этом group by. И тот факт, что один запрос можно обернуть в from другого, что бы работать с ним как с таблицей, не используя временные таблицы. Обычно как бы изучают сначала базовые вещи, а до оконных вообще мало кто доходит. Но за смекалку с оконными плюсую :)

Comment: Спасибо большое! В моей постановке, это то что надо!! Я начинающий, верно )) У меня в реальности, есть и прочие столбцы: col3, ..., colX. И должен был в условии на них тоже указать: